# Accessing unique deeply nested objects in surrealDB SurrealQL

Tags: surrealdb

I have a surreal database in which I am storing data in separate tables through record links. The following tables exist:

- Show
- Event
- Competitions
- Arena

The relationship between the data is represented such that events and competitions are arrays, so each show has multiple events, each event has multiple competitions and each competition has 1 arena.

```
show {
  events [{
    competitions [{
      arena {
        name
      }
    }]
  }]
}
```

When I try to query this data using the dot notation from SurrealQL, instead of getting a representation of the form of the data, I instead have each competition returning an array of arrays of all stadiums, and then stage is also returned as an array of arrays.
I have tried `event.competitions.arena.name` and `event.*.competitions.*.arena.name`, however both of these return the same issue.

TL;DR

```json
// Expected output
[
    {
        "events": [
            {
               "competitions": [
                    {
                        "arena": {
                            "id": "arena:tyv123",
                            "name": "Arena 1"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "arena": {
                            "id": "arena:tyv123",
                            "name": "Arena 1"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "competitions": [
                    {
                        "arena": {
                            "id": "arena:tyv123",
                            "name": "Arena 1"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "arena": {
                            "id": "arena:tyv123",
                            "name": "Arena 1"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "arena": {
                            "id": "arena:tyv124",
                            "name": "Arena 2"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]

// Actual output 
[
    {
        "events": {
            "competitions": {
                "arena": [
                    [
                        {
                            "id": "arena:tyv123",
                            "name": "Arena 1"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "arena:tyv123",
                            "name": "Arena 1"
                        }
                    ],
                    [
                        {
                            "id": "arena:tyv123",
                            "name": "Arena 1"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "arena:tyv123",
                            "name": "Arena 1"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "arena:tyv124",
                            "name": "Arena 2"
                        }
                    ]
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so after reading through the docs, a couple more times, turns out it's perfectly simple: You simply use the `*` selector, and then append a `FETCH` statement to the end.
The correct syntax should have been:

```
SELECT * FROM show FETCH events, events.competitions, events.competitions.arena;
```